# Need help to understand the output of this code

Tags: c

see my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
int main(int argc, char**argv) {

    unsigned char *message = NULL;

    struct stat stp = { 0 };
    stat("huffman.txt", &stp);
    /*determine the size of data which is in file*/
    int filesize = stp.st_size;
    printf("\nFile size id %d\n", filesize);

    FILE* original_fileptr = fopen("huffman.txt", "r");
    message =  malloc(filesize);
    fread(message, 1, filesize, original_fileptr);
    printf("\n\tEntered Message for Encode is %s= and length %d", message,strlen(message));

    return 0;
}
```

here huffman.txt has size 20 bytes and following character are there

Î¬­SUä5Ñ®qøá"F„œ

**output of this code is**

```
File size id 20

        Entered Message for Encode is Î¬­SUä5Ñ®qøá"F„œ= and length 21
```

now question is if size is 20 then why length is 21 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C doesn't have native strings, only arrays of characters, and there is a hidden, ubiquitous assumption that the last array member is a zero.

Since you violate that assumption by reading only 20 bytes into an array of 20 elements, with no regard to whether the final byte is zero, and then using *string* features like `%s` and `strlen`, you get essentially undefined behavior.

Getting an answer of 21 is pure luck; anything (far worse) could have happened.

Correct code could be something like this (assuming the file is a text file):

```
char * buf = calloc(filesize + 1, 1);  /* yay, already zeroed! */
fread(buf, 1, filesize, fp);
printf("File contents: '%s'\nFile content size: %u.\n", buf, strlen(buf));
```

If you're reading arbitrary ("binary") files, this will generally not produce the expected result (unless you know what to expect).

Comment: "far worse" would range from a segmentation violation to information disclosure.

Comment: @ninjalj: This is the very archetypal example of a programming error that's at the heart of hundreds of serious exploitable vulnerabilities that can and have been used for serious break-ins... indeed, understanding this one concept may be one of the most important aspects of knowing C.